# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.b-brand-box'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to call a JavaScript function from jQuery. When I try to pass an argument to JavaScript function:

```
var brandRcObj = "b-brand-box";

$('.b-brand-box').on('mouseleave', function(){
    brandOn(brandRcObj);
});
```

I am getting the following error:

```
"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.b-brand-box'"
```

I'm doing this because I will use the same `mouseleave` event multiple times in my project. Therefore I wanted to write a JavaScript function as follows:

```
function brandOn(brandClass){

  var classObj = "'" + "." + brandClass + "'";
  var imgObj = "'" + "." + brandClass + " " + "img" + "'";

  $(classObj).css({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    opacity: 1
  });
  $(imgObj).css({
    opacity: 1
  });
}
```

Thanks for yor help!

Comment: what line is the error on in the code you show?

Comment: Robert, it says jquery-1.10.1.js:1924(Sizzle). When I debug it I see that It does not work after line: "$(classObj).css" in my javascript funtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'.b-brand-box'` is not a valid class selector – `.b-brand-box` is.

You are putting single quotes around the value you are dynamically generating, although *there should not be any* – you are mistaking the *notation* of a text literal in JavaScript *syntax* for its actual string *value*.

`'.b-brand-box'` is the notation of a text literal in JavaScript *code*, `".b-brand-box"` would be another valid way of writing it. The *value* of both of those strings after the source code has been parsed is only `.b-brand-box` however.

What you actually want is just simply

```
"." + brandClass;
```

and nothing more.

Comment: Thank you very much CBroe!! That worked! I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need all those quotes, where you have:

```
var classObj = "'" + "." + brandClass + "'";
var imgObj = "'" + "." + brandClass + " " + "img" + "'";
```

all you need is

```
var classObj = "." + brandClass; 
var imgObj = "." + brandClass + " " + "img";
```

The interpreter knows you have a string

Comment: Don’t know, because you are right of course (and I answered basically the same thing). +1 from me.

Comment: @CBroe somebody probably though my first block of code was my answer, thanks